# How to read changing data from the ELD module and display this data in the application?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

Please tell me how I can correctly receive exactly the changing data via Bluetooth from the ELD module. I use the [flutter_blue_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus) package. The application scans devices, finds the one you need, and connects to it. I read all the characteristics and when I try to display them in the application in a user-friendly form, I only get the name of the module, its version. and something else. But I cannot display variable data, such as the state of the engine, track, etc. where can I find and read these specifications?

I would be grateful for any information.

Here is my code for reading characteristics

```
List serviceChar = [];
dynamic globalService;

Future onDiscoverServicesPressed() async {
    // BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic;
    setState(() {
      _isDiscoveringServices = true;
    });
    try {
      _services = await widget.device.discoverServices();
      for (var ser in _services) {
        for (var char in ser.characteristics) {
          if (char.properties.read) {
            List<int> value = await char.read();
            setState(() {
              globalService = String.fromCharCodes(value);
              // globalService = utf8.decode(value);
              serviceChar.add(globalService);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Snackbar.show(ABC.c, prettyException("Discover Services Error:", e), success: false);
    }
    setState(() {
      _isDiscoveringServices = false;
    });
  }
```

this is what I can only get in the application
first photo all characteristics

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2G2X.jpg

second photo reading characteristics and converting to readable form
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwsww.jpg

But I can’t get changeable data about the state of the engine and so on. Maybe I'm not reading the characteristics correctly or reading the wrong characteristics?